# Cannot get any generators to work

Tags: node.js, command-line, npm, generator, yeoman

I usually build my apps using some sort of Yeoman generator, but have been unable to get any of them working. I am getting tons of errors in the command line no matter which generator I try to use. Right now, I am trying to use gulp webapp, which can be seen here: https://github.com/yeoman/generator-gulp-webapp.

I type yo gulp-webapp, which appears to work for a bit, then after it says:
"I'm all done. Running bower install & npm install for you to install the required dependencies. If this fails, try running the command yourself.",

I get TONS of errors. Here's a sampling of the first ten or so:

```
npm WARN package.json mgportfolio@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json mgportfolio@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json mgportfolio@0.0.0 No README data
npm WARN deprecated gulp-clean@0.2.4: use gulp-rimraf instead
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/Users/margaretgodowns/Documents/theIronYard/mgPortfolio/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/gulp-util/lib/isNull.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.4.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/margaretgodowns/Documents/theIronYard/mgPortfolio
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
```

This has happened with generators across the board today. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: if you're dealing with `node.js` code (even using a generator), best to include a tag for that. Note the low number of followers for all of your tags (except command-line (which is how I saw your question;-) ) . Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, I added that. Still new to StackOverflow so that's helpful to know.